# Design for importing definition data from Excel into SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, database-design, import

We have Restaurant Inventory Control system that uses SQL Server 2008 R2.

It takes a very long time to add all the definition data: stock items, yields, packsizes, recipes, categories etc. So, our clients have asked if they can upload it from Excel.

Before I just jump in and start, I want to find out if there is a best practice way to do this.

I know all the tools: SSIS, stored procedures etc. But I'm looking for advice/resources that can help with the design process. How best to setup the spreadsheet, validate the data, create the child/parent relationships etc.

This must be a fairly common project -- so it must have a standard design/approach and that's what I'm looking for.

Comment: Will the excel data be hand generated?

Comment: Probably exported from another system and then formatted into our Excel template

Comment: If iti  sbeing exported from another system, tehn do not accept it as Excel files (which are horrible to import for a variety of reason in SSIS). Instead ask fora a text file (pipe-delimited) or a csv file. Those are much easier to convert and don't tend to have the problem Excel has when a field contains but numeric looking and aplanumeric data (like a part number).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the design will depend on the technologies you're most comfortable with. If you're comfortable with SSIS and stored procedures, this is the general pattern I would use:

1. **Excel Template** - I wouldn't spend too much time on this, add the headers and sheets necessary for the tables. You can lock down certain things and/or implement rules, but most of your validation would be done in stored procs.
2. **SSIS** - Have a package that loads the excel data into Staging tables, have rows with errors get added to an error log to be presented to the user along with the validation issues from the stored procedures.
3. **Staging Tables** - Have one staging table per sheet/production table, have an ExecutionId column in each staging table to allow parallel processing. Allow all columns to be NULL so you can get the data in the staging tables or set the proper null conditions and have SSIS redirect these rows on error. Don't have any primary key / foreign key relationships in the staging tables, these can be validated in the stored procedure
4. **Stored Procedures** - Validate the staging data, any issues found would be added to the error log to be presented to the user or person performing the import. If there are no issues, import the data into the production tables. If there is existing data in the production tables, you could do a comparison and update if applicable.

Comment: We have two staging tables, one for the raw data as it came in and another that contains the cleanup up data. This saves tons of time in tracking down what happened when there is an import problem. We also throw all bad rtrecords to an exception table so they can be examined, sent back to the provider of the data to fix or analyzed to see ifa new cleaning routine is needed.